# multiple ggplots in for loop, always same plot

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, ggplot2

So I have a dataframe tmp, and each column follows different distributions. What I want to do is plot the histograms in a pdf, each page a histogram. But why do I get three times the same histogram?

When I type in g11 I get the histogram g13, but when I plot the histograms in the pdf, instead of 3 identical pages (with histograms 1-3), I get 3 different pages with the same histogram on it.

Might it be that ggplot works with a pointer, and that due to the second for-loop, it plots g1i?

Is there a way to rewrite my code? (The example is simplified from my problem)

```
    tmp <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n=20, mean=0, sd=1),
                  y=rnorm(n=20, mean=10, sd=2),
                  z=rnorm(n=20, mean=40, sd=5))

for (i in 1:3){
  assign(paste("g1", i, sep=""),ggplot(tmp,aes(x=get(colnames(tmp)[i]))) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1))
}

pdf("/pathto/plot.pdf")
for(i in 1:3){
  #i <- 1
  grid.arrange(get(paste("g1", 1, sep="")), get(paste("g1", 2, sep="")), get(paste("g1", 3, sep="")))
}
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `get` in the first for loop is not changing the column correctly.
You could try this instead:

```
for (i in 1:3){
    assign(paste("g1", i, sep=""),ggplot(tmp,aes_string(x=colnames(tmp)[i])) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1))
}
```

Comment: It worked! Simple and easy workaround. But what is aes_string doing? (I read the help page, but it would be good to know how ggplot works and why it is not creating a "closed" object)

Comment: Usually ggplot evaluates the values inside `aes` names lazily, so it takes the values you pass and looks for them in the parent data.frame (that's why you don't have to quote them normally). However, if you use `colnames` what you are returning is a string, so you have to tell ggplot explicitly that the arguments inside `aes`  are quoted strings by using `aes_string`. There are other workarounds, but I thought this would be the most straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite it like in the code below.
First I would put the data from wide to long format and then subset each level (x, y, z) and plot it.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

tmp <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n=20, mean=0, sd=1),
                  y=rnorm(n=20, mean=10, sd=2),
                  z=rnorm(n=20, mean=40, sd=5))

xy <- gather(tmp)

pdf("histogram.pdf")
for (i in unique(xy$key)) {
  x <- droplevels(xy[xy$key == i, ])
  print(
    ggplot(x, aes(x = value)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_histogram()
  )
}
dev.off()
```